# Прямая или косвенная речь?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такой анекдот (пишу, как были расставлены знаки препинания там, где я его прочитала): "Штирлиц долго смотрел в одну точку. Потом в другую. "Двоеточие" — догадался Штирлиц".
Меня интересует, является ли слово "двоеточие" прямой речью? А если нет, то что это и как оформляется пунктуационно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, этот прямая речь. Надо только поставить запятую после прямой речи. *"Двоеточие", — догадался Штирлиц".*